# for looping in python 3 not doing what I want it to do

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I try to make this code for my little one to practice simple mathematics
and I want to give to the user 3 problems to solve, but the program runs random times of problems. What is it I have done wrong? 
Thanks

```
import random

for i in range(3):             # number of problems          

    for n in range(999):
        num1 = random.randrange(11)
        num2 = random.randrange(11)
        if num1<num2:
            break
        else:
            sum = eval(input("how much is {} - {} = ".format(num1,num2)))
            if sum == num1 - num2:
                print ("Good job!")
                break      

        for x in range(5):           #nr of wrong tries     
            if sum != num1 - num2:
                sum = eval(input("Try again {} - {} = ".format(num1,num2)))
            else:
                print ("Good job!")
                break
```

Comment: You didn't explain what your question is.  What do you want your program to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: HI , 
Like I said , I want the program to give 3 different problems to the user like this: how much is 2-2=      how much is 3-2=    how much is 6-1= 
but it gives 2 or 1 or 0 problems and some times 3 problems as well

Comment: If `num1 < num2` is true you'll break out of the inner for loop, so it'll run 3 or less questions. Use `continue` instead of `break`, or even better, use a `while` loop. `while` loops are used for looping until a condition is met while `for` loops are used when you know how many times you want to loop.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
import random

for i in range(3):             # number of problems          
    num1 = random.randrange(11)
    num2 = random.randrange(11)

    while num1<num2:
        num1 = random.randrange(11)
        num2 = random.randrange(11)

    sum = input("how much is {} - {} = ".format(num1,num2))

    for x in range(5):           #nr of wrong tries     
        if sum != num1 - num2:
            sum = input("Try again {} - {} = ".format(num1,num2))
        else:
            print ("Good job!")
            break
```

I just replaced an unwanted `for` loop and `if` statement with a `while`.

Comment: Some more explanation of what you did would be useful to the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the structure of your program, it's confusing, which is why you're here, and error prone, also why you're here.

Try something like this pseudocode:

```
loop three times
  num1 = -1
  num2 = 0
  while(num1 < num2)
    assign random numbers to num1 and num2
  end loop

  input = ask user what num2 - num1 is

  if input == num2 - num1
    print 'yay'
  else
    print 'boo'
  end if

end loop
```

This cleans things up and gets rid of those breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If `num1 < num2` is true you'll break out of the inner for loop, so it'll run 3  questions or less, depending on how many times `num1 < num2` is `True`. Quickest fix would be to change the `break` to `continue` inside that `if` block.

However, it's better to use a `while` loop when you don't know how many times you want to loop, and only want to stop when a certain condition is met. In your case you want to loop until `num1 > num2`, and then ask the question.

An even better solution would be to generate a random number `num1` between 1-10 and then generate a random number `num2` between 0-`num1`, which always will make sure `num1` is greater than `num2`.

Last notes:

- Use `int` to convert the input to an integer instead of `eval`.
- `sum` is a built-in function so use another name so you don't shadow it.

Here's a functioning example:

```
import random

for i in range(3):
    num1 = random.randrange(1, 11)  # Has to be greater than 0 so num2 can be less.
    num2 = random.randrange(num1)

    # Use 'int' to convert to int, not 'eval'!
    # Also, 'sum' is a built-in function. Don't shadow it, use another name.
    result = int(input("how much is {} - {} = ".format(num1, num2)))  

    for x in range(5):  # nr of wrong tries     
        if result != num1 - num2:
            result = int(input("Try again {} - {} = ".format(num1, num2)))
        else:
            print("Good job!")
            break
```

You can expand on this by adding a `try-catch` block to makes sure that the input really is an number. The program will crash if you input anything else than digits. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/6486738) is how you can validate the input.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies 

Ted Klein Bergman yours is spot on , very informative and it works as I intended thanks